# Python: Printing a List from a starting point to a defined range

Tags: python, list, printing, tuples, fibonacci

This is my code; I know its a mess, but I'm just getting through the basics if that. The question that I have is with the printing of a list at the end. You see, I've tried quite a few things, but it keeps telling me either that "'list' object is not callable" or "Unexpected type: Tuple..." Now, tuple doesn't mean anything to me because we haven't reached that point in class, but I don't want a tuple anyway. I want to print a list that starts at the indicated point "f" with a range of "f2". But I just can't get that.
What am I doing wrong?

```
def main():
    f = int(input("Starting Place in Code: "))
    message = input("simple message: ")
    f2 = len(message)
    messageList = []
    fibonacciNumbers = [0, 1]
    messageNumList = []
    f3 = fibonacciNumbers[f: f+f2]

    for let in message:
        messageList.append(let)

    for let in messageList:
        messageNumList.append(ord(let))

    for i in range(2, 700):
        fibonacciNumbers.append(fibonacciNumbers[i - 1] + fibonacciNumbers[i - 2])

    #print(fibonacciNumbers)
    print(f3)
    print(f2)
    print(messageList)
    print(messageNumList)
main()

Starting Place in Code: 5
simple message: fish
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, ...]
[5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
4
['f', 'i', 's', 'h']
[102, 105, 115, 104]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You are printing based on the ranges of values or order in list?

Comment: I believe I found the issue:
"f" is the starting location int the fib. sequence, but I'm inserting a word with too few characters "f2", so it's trying to print something to a point prior to the starting point. This of course doesn't work.
I want it to continue from the point it indicated "f" an amount of steps indicated by "f2".

WAIT: I got it!
Just had to add "f" to "f2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think you've identified it's the `fibonacciNumbers[f, f2]` that's the problem. So two parts:

1) What's the right syntax to slice a list? Separate the indices with a `:`, not `,`. So `fibonacciNumbers[f:f2]` (note that the last index in the slice will be `f2-1`, so you may want `fibonacciNumbers[f:f2+1]`). (Edit: Just to be clear `l[i:j]` means "give me elements `i, i+1, ..., j-1` of list `l`, not "give me `j` elements starting from index `i`.")

2) What does the error mean? A tuple is like a list, but fixed--you can't change or add elements: `(1,2,3)` is a tuple, `[1,2,3]` is a list. Sometimes the parentheses are unnecessary. When you write `fibonacciNumbers[f, f2]`, Python is interpreting it as "give me the element of the list whose index is the tuple `(f,f2)`", which doesn't make sense, hence the exception. (You can see variations by, say, trying to access element `"a"` of a list.)

I'm guessing "'list' object is not callable" happened when you wrote something like `fibonacciNumbers(f,f2)`. With parentheses, you're calling a function called `fibonacciNumbers`, but it's a list not a function and is therefore not callable.

Comment: Thank you for those corrections; they're working wonders!
However, now, when I assign "f" the input "5" ( or anything above 2 really), it leaves the printed list blank.